# Limit characters on PHP RSS Feed Import

Tags: php, rss, character, limit, feed

I'm currently developing a website that requires an RSS to pull in certain product details from another website such as image, description, link etc.

RSS Feed works perfectly using PHP, exactly as I need it to, however the descriptions are way too long.

How would you go about limiting the amount of characters outputted from the description tag in the RSS Feed?

Code:

```html
<div class="row product-grid">
  <?php $rss=n ew DOMDocument(); $rss->load('http://www.itclear.com/BestSellers.xml'); $feed = array(); foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item) { $item = array ( 'title' => $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue, 'desc' => $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'link' => $item->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue, 'image' => $item->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0)->nodeValue, 'price' => $item->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0)->nodeValue, ); array_push($feed, $item); } $limit = 20;
  for($x=0;$x
  <$limit;$x++) { $title=s tr_replace( ' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x][ 'title']); $link=$ feed[$x][ 'link']; $description=$ feed[$x][ 'desc']; $image=$ feed[$x][ 'image']; $price=$ feed[$x][ 'price']; echo '
                <div class="xsmall-12 medium-6 large-3 columns product">
                    <h2 class="product-title"><strong><a href="'.$link. '" title="'.$title. '">'.$title. '</a></strong></h2>
                    <img class="product-image" src="'.$image. '"/>
                    <p class="product-description">'.$description. '</p>
                    <p class="product-price">'.$price. '</p>
                </div>
                '; } ?>
</div>
<!-- End of product grid -->
```